# deallocate()でエラーが出てバッファを解放できない

Tags: xcode, swift4

■環境
Mac/High Sierra 10.13.6/swift4.2/xcode 10.0

iosアプリで音を取得して解析することを繰り返すアプリを作成しようと思い、
https://qiita.com/a_jike/items/68dd13879f9df5b2b7a2
上記urlサイトを参考にさせていただきました。
そこのサイトに著者のGitHub上のコードが公開されておりました。下記のURLです。
https://github.com/atsushijike/AudioService

そこでこのソースの動作確認をしようとしたのですが、
AudioServiceクラスのdeinit内にリソース解放のための
buffer.deallocate()が記述されています。

```
deinit{
    buffer.deallocate()
}
```

しかし、動かしてみると
error for object 0x11a94f000: pointer being freed was not allocated
というメッセージが出ました。

試しにbuffer.deallocate()を消してみると通りましたが、bufferが解放されていないのでは無いかと思います。
しっかりと解放する方法を知りたいのですが、調べてもなかなか見つけることができませんでした。
解決のためご助言賜りたいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

コードの中身を見る限り、`NSData`や`NSMutableData`を多用していて、とてもSwift的に綺麗なコードとは言えないですね。著者に届かないところでケチをつけてもしかたないことなんで、これ以上は控えますが。

問題のエラーは解放済みの領域を再度解放(二重解放)しようとした時に表示されるものです。解放し過ぎなんですから、条件によっては`buffer.deallocate()`を削除することで解消できる可能性がありますが、別の条件ではご心配いただいているように領域の解放漏れでメモリリークが生じる可能性があります。

一番問題なのは、この行です。

AudioService.swift: 92行:

```
data = NSData(bytesNoCopy: buffer, length: Int(maxPacketCount * bytesPerPacket))
```

`NSData.init(bytesNoCopy:length:)`と言うイニシャライザは`buffer`の所有権を引き継ぐ、つまり、`buffer`の解放は`NSData`の側が行うので、これを一度呼び出したら、`buffer`を割り当てた側がその領域を解放する処理を呼び出してはいけません。

> ### [`init(bytesNoCopy:length:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1409454-init)
>
> #### Declaration
>
> ```
> init(bytesNoCopy bytes: UnsafeMutableRawPointer, length: Int)
> ```
>
> #### Discussion
>
> The returned object takes ownership of the `bytes` pointer and frees it
>   on deallocation. Therefore, `bytes` must point to a memory block
>   allocated with `malloc`.
>
> (拙訳)
>   返された`NSData`オブジェクトが`bytes`ポインターの所有権を引き継ぎ、その`NSData`オブジェクトが廃棄(deallocation)される時にその領域を`free`で解放します。従って、`bytes`は`malloc`で割り当てられたメモリ領域を指すものでないといけません。

元のコードは「`malloc`で割り当てられたメモリ領域を指すものでないといけません」は守っているようですが、前半の事情がわかっていないようです。このイニシャライザを呼んだ後は、自前で同じ領域を解放すると冒頭に書いたような二重解放のエラー(場合によってはうまく検出されず、重大かつデバッグ困難な不具合となります)になります。

---

現象の説明が長くなってしまいましたが、先の行を次のように書き換えれば、**`buffer`についての** 二重解放の問題はなくなります。

```
data = NSData(bytesNoCopy: buffer, length: Int(maxPacketCount * bytesPerPacket), freeWhenDone: false)
```

`freeWhenDone: false`と言う引数を追加することにより、所有権は`NSData`の側に移らず、引き続き`buffer`を割り当てた側がその領域を解放する責任を持つことになります。

---

ただ、イニシャライザとデイニシャライザが全然釣り合っていませんね。

```
init(_ obj: Any?) {
    startingPacketCount = 0
    maxPacketCount = (48000 * seconds)
    buffer = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(malloc(Int(maxPacketCount * bytesPerPacket)))
}

deinit {
    buffer.deallocate()
}
```

`buffer`は`malloc`で割り当てられているのですから、解放は`free`で行うべきです。(**現在のSwiftの実装では**`deallocate()`は内部で`free`を呼んでいるだけなので、動くことは動くでしょうが。)

また、そもそもSwiftの`malloc`の戻り値型は`UnsafeMutableRawPointer!`型になるので、型変換のために`UnsafeMutableRawPointer(` `)`で囲んでやる必要もありません。

なんで使いもしていない`obj`なんて引数があるのか、なんてことも解せないんですが、とりあえずそれは置いといて、以下のように描き直すべきでしょう。

```
init(_ obj: Any?) {
    startingPacketCount = 0
    maxPacketCount = (48000 * seconds)
    buffer = malloc(Int(maxPacketCount * bytesPerPacket))
}

deinit {
    free(buffer)
}
```

ついでに47行、`buffer`は一度割り当てられたら気安く書き換えられては困るので`var`ではなく`let`の方が良いですね。(他にも`let`にした方が良いものはまだありそうですが。)

```
let buffer: UnsafeMutableRawPointer
```

---

まだまだ、メモリ絡みで何か出てきそうな気もしますが、これ以上は本題から外れすぎるように思うので、深追いはせずに置きます。

上記の修正を行えば、二重解放でのエラーは起こらなくなるはずなのでお試しください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。とても勉強になりました。swiftのAudio関係の説明について公式ドキュメントが非常にわかりにくい印象でした。特にポインタあたりを正確に理解していなければならないことがわかりました。swiftのポインタについて公式ドキュメントでわかりづらい部分はやはりC言語などのポインタの基礎がわかっていないためでしょうか。普段のプログラミングではあまりポインタを意識するようなものをやらないためその辺りの知識がぼんやりしています。

Comment: @shin-ichi さん、ご返信ありがとうございます。Appleのドキュメントについてはおっしゃる通りで、私もよく「公式ドキュメント見ろ」と言う意味の回答を書くのですが、公式ドキュメントだけ見ていてもなんのこっちゃわからない、肝心なことが何も書いていない、なんてのはザラにあります。あくまで「情報源の一つ」「(何か書いてあれば)信頼すべき情報」として捉えてください。SwiftのポインタについてはC言語のポインタに精通しているかたでも、わかりにくいところがいっぱいあります。ただ、解析を含むようなオーディオ処理ではポインタは避けては通れません。特に今回のように古いCore AudioのC言語用APIをSwiftから使うなんて言うと、Swiftについてはかなりのベテランでも完全に正しいコードになっていることは稀です。(私も昔公開していたコードなんかには結構ポインタのやばい使い方なんかがありました。今でも残っているかも。)今回のようなテンプレ的なコード例を読むのと、公式のAPI仕様をしっかり読むのとを併行して、自分のやりたいことに近付くまで着実に覚えていかれれば良いと思います。

Comment: さん、ありがとうございます。<https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/49523/バッファの先頭アドレスを変更したいデータを追加した分先頭を削除したい>に質問を投稿させていただいたいのですが、今の場合bufferはUnsafeMutableRawPointerで取り出すとこきにNSDataとしてさらにlet bytes = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: data.bytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: Int8.self), count: datalength)としてsubscriptで取り出しているものと理解しておりますが、こういったものを先頭を削除して、後ろにデータを付け加えたいとした場合にはUnsafeBufferPointerでデータをいじっておき、NSDataに変換してNSDataをself.bufferにコピーするということを行えば、バッファの長さはそのままに、録音を続けることができますでしょうか。

Comment: @shin-ichi さん、新規の別質問の方は読ませていただいているんですが、今参考にされているプロジェクトを発展させるのは難しいだろうと言うことでコメントなり回答の形で何か書き込むのは躊躇しています。参考までにリアルタイムで音声のFFT解析他を行う[Apple製サンプルコード(のSwiftへの移植版)](https://github.com/ooper-shlab/aurioTouch2.0-Swift)のリンクを示しておきます。若干不要な部分もあるでしょうが、リアルタイムで音の波形の解析を行いながらその結果も表示すると言うことになると、この程度の複雑さにはなると言うことで。また、時間が取れましたら本来のご質問の方にコメントさせていただきます。

Comment: @OOPerさん、ありがとうございます。大変参考になります。OOPerさんのコードを拝読させていただき、勉強いたします。質問に書きましたhttps://github.com/atsushijike/AudioService
のコードについてなのですが、16bitで取得しているにもにかかわらず、WaveView.swiftにてlet bytes = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: data.bytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: Int8.self), count: length)とInt8に直して記載していました。これではおかしな結果にならないでしょうか。Int16もしくはUInt16が正しいのかなと思ったのですが。

Comment: @shin-ichi さん、おっしゃる通りですね。`AudioServices`クラスでは16bit符号付整数を指定しているので符号付きである`Int16`を指定しないといけません。(`count`もそれに合わせて補正しないといけませんが。)取得した標本データを8bitに変換したり、8bitで取得したデータを2個組み合わせて16bitに変換するような処理はどこにも見当たらないので、元コードの誤りでしょう。音声波形なんてパッと見では正しいかどうかわからないギザギザデータになるので、間違えたままで公表されているのでしょう。残念ながらこの手の誤りを含んだコードは検索結果の上位にうようよと見つかります。