# バッファの先頭アドレスを変更したい(データを追加した分先頭を削除したい)

Tags: xcode, swift4, ポインタ

■環境
Mac/High Sierra 10.13.6/swift4.2/xcode 10.0

iosアプリで音を取得して解析することを繰り返すアプリを作成しようと思い、
https://qiita.com/a_jike/items/68dd13879f9df5b2b7a2
上記urlサイトを参考にさせていただきました。
そこのサイトに著者のGitHub上のコードが公開されておりました。下記のURLです。
https://github.com/atsushijike/AudioService

上記ソースコードのwritePackets(inBuffer: AudioQueueBufferRef)関数の中で、バッファのコピーがおこなわれていますが、そこでmaxPacketCountよりstartingPacketCount+numPacketsが大きい場合に、書き込んだら溢れてしまう

```
n = startingPacketCount+numPackets-maxPacketCount
```

の数だけ先頭要素を削除し、後ろに要素を新たにn個要素を追加したうえで書き込みを行いたいです。
録音がずっと止まらないようにバッファ不足分だけ先頭をずらして後ろに足していくイメージです。大枠としての案は下記の２点かと思うのですが、その方法がわからず質問致しました。

■案１
直接バッファの先頭を削除し、後ろに削除した分の要素を追加する
何かの関数でバッファの特定部分を削除し、追加したい分だけ結合する？
配列のイメージで書くと以下のようになります
バッファの削除したい先頭の要素数がnの時

```
for _ in 0 ..< n{
    b1.removeFirst()
    b1.append(書き込みたいデータ)
}
```

■案２
バッファb2を用意し、元のバッファb1から先頭の不要部分を除いたところを先に書き込み、
今回書き込みたい分をb2に追加してからb2をb1にコピー
配列のイメージで書くと以下のようになります
バッファの削除したい先頭の要素数がnの時

```
for i in n ..< b1.count{
    b2[i-n] = b1[i]
}
for i in b1.count-n ..< b1.count{
    b2[i] = (書き込みたいデータ)
}
b1 = b2
```

Comment: **_案1_** `malloc`(あるいは`UnsafeMutablePointer.allocate`)で割り当てられた領域に対しては、`removeFirst()`, `append()`のような操作はできません。例えば`Array`型の内部では、案2に相当する操作を実際に行なっています。 **_案2_** やろうと思えばできますし、`buffer`全体の大きさが実は変わらないなら、「バッファb2」なんて用意しなくても、元の`buffer`の中で残す部分を順に前に詰めていけば実現できます。が、あまりオススメしたくない書き方です。と言うのは、波形データが届くのはせいぜい数KB単位であるのに対し、`buffer`のサイズは48000×2×10 =960000で、約1MBあります。数KBのデータが届くたびに1MBのバッファを全体を操作すると言うのはあまりにも非効率です。最近の高速なCPUなら一応動きはするでしょうが、データを右から左までずらすためだけにとんでもないCPUパワーを食うことになり、信号解析に使える余地は大きく減るでしょう。

Comment: と言うわけでリングバッファを使うようなやり方を提案したいところですが、それをやると元コードのかなりの部分を書き換えることになるでしょう。その後「音を取得して解析することを繰り返す」ことができるようになるまでにも課題は山積みですが…。と言うわけでこの先どのように課題を解決していくのか方向性が見えないと「(あなたにとって)これがベスト」とはなかなか言いにくい内容です。現在参考になさっているコードがほとんど使えなくなる、なんてことになっても、「(私にとって)これがベスト」と言う回答に付き合ってみる気はおありでしょうか。目的までの近道ということであれば、他のサンプルコードを探してもらった方が早いかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。リングバッファについて大変興味があります。やはりswiftのバッファの扱い、ポインタの扱い、そしてAudioToolBoxの扱いが難しいです。やりたいことについて後半の解析部分についてはできており、課題として残っているのはこの部分のみになります。やりたいことは上記の通りで、最初に決めたバッファサイズを大きくすることなく録音されたデータを録音用のバッファからバッファへ詰めていき、サイズがいっぱいのところで先頭を消して、後ろに詰めるということができれば自分の目的はほぼ達成できます。ぜひOOPerさんのご回答におつきあいさせていただきたいです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

見てみたいと言うコメントをいただいたので、回答として示させてもらいます。300行近い長いコードですが、ほぼ全面的に修正しているので全行そのまま掲載します。

---

その前にざっとリングバッファの説明だけ。

```
|<-                maxSampleCount              ->|
|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|
```

現在入っているデータの先頭と、次に書き込むべきデータの位置を保持することにより、このバッファの一部だけを使用していることを記録しておきます。

```
|<-                maxSampleCount              ->|
|xxxxxxx|-     usingSampleCount     ->|xxxxxxxxxx|
        ↑
        startingSampleIndex
```

(xxxxは未使用領域。)

空いている場所に書き込むだけなら、場所をずらさずに続きに書き込んでいきます。

```
|<-                maxSampleCount              ->|
|xxxxxxx|-     usingSampleCount       ---->|xxxxx|
        ↑
        startingSampleIndex
```

(書き込んだ分`usingSampleCount`を増やす。)

もういらなくなったデータがあれば、前に詰めるのではなく、2つの情報をちょっと書き換えるだけです。

```
|<-                maxSampleCount              ->|
|xxxxxxxxxxxx|-usingSampleCount       ---->|xxxxx|
        -----↑
             startingSampleIndex
```

(`usingSampleCount`は減らす。`startingSampleIndex`は増やす。)

領域がバッファの終端を跨いだらどうなるのか、ちょっと面倒くさくなりますが、雰囲気は掴んでもらえると思います。

---

以上の内容をコードにしたのがこちら。原則として元の`AudioService`クラスと同じ構成になるようにしていますが、

- プロパティ名やメソッド名を見直し
- `NSData`を`Data`に変更
- `buffer`を`UnsafeMutableRawPointer`から`UnsafeMutablePointer<Int16>`に

と、リングバッファ化と合わせ中身は大幅に変わっているので、クラス名も`AudioService`から`MyAudioService`に変更してあります。特に「余分なデータを削除してしまう」と言う処理の必要な`writeSamples(inBuffer:)`メソッドには少し細かめのコメントをつけておいたので確認してみてください。

```
import Foundation
import AudioToolbox

extension Notification.Name {
    static let audioServiceDidUpdateData = Notification.Name(rawValue: "AudioServiceDidUpdateDataNotification")
}

func myAudioQueueInputCallback(inUserData: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?,
                               inAQ: AudioQueueRef,
                               inBuffer: AudioQueueBufferRef,
                               inStartTime: UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>,
                               inNumberPacketDescriptions: UInt32,
                               inPacketDescs: UnsafePointer<AudioStreamPacketDescription>?) {
    let audioService: MyAudioService = Unmanaged.fromOpaque(inUserData!).takeUnretainedValue()
    print(audioService)
    audioService.writeSamples(inBuffer: inBuffer)
    AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(inAQ, inBuffer, 0, nil);

    print("startingPacketCount: \(audioService.startingSampleIndex), maxPacketCount: \(audioService.maxSampleCount)")
    //「録音がずっと止まらないように」と言うことなので、ここでは録音の停止は判定しない
}

func myAudioQueueOutputCallback(inUserData: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?,
                                inAQ: AudioQueueRef,
                                inBuffer: AudioQueueBufferRef) {
    let audioService: MyAudioService = Unmanaged.fromOpaque(inUserData!).takeUnretainedValue()
    audioService.readSamples(inBuffer: inBuffer)
    AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(inAQ, inBuffer, 0, nil)

    print("playingSampleCount: \(audioService.playingSampleCount), maxPacketCount: \(audioService.maxSampleCount)")
    if audioService.playingSampleCount == 0 {
        audioService.stop()
    }
}

class MyAudioService {
    let buffer: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int16>
    let maxSampleCount: Int
    //バッファ内の有効データの開始位置
    var startingSampleIndex: Int = 0
    //バッファ内の有効データの数
    var usingSampleCount: Int = 0
    //再生中の位置
    var playingSampleIndex: Int = 0
    //再生用の残りデータの数
    var playingSampleCount: Int = 0

    var audioQueueObject: AudioQueueRef?

    let numSamplesToRead: Int = 1024
    let numSamplesToWrite: Int = 1024

    let seconds: Int = 10 //`buffer`に格納可能な最大秒数
    let sampleRate: Int = 48_000 //サンプリングレート(Hz)
    let framesPerPacket: Int = 1 //Lenear PCM の場合1フレーム=1パケット
    let channelsPerFrame: Int = 1 //Monoral: 1フレーム辺りのチャンネル数は1(2ch Stereoなら2とする)
    let bytesPerSample: Int = MemoryLayout<Int16>.stride

    let inBufferCount = 3
    let outBufferCount = 3

    let audioFormat: AudioStreamBasicDescription

    var data: Data? {
        didSet {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .audioServiceDidUpdateData, object: self)
        }
    }

    init() {
        let bytesPerPacket = bytesPerSample * framesPerPacket * channelsPerFrame
        audioFormat = AudioStreamBasicDescription(
            mSampleRate: Float64(sampleRate),
            mFormatID: kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
            mFormatFlags: AudioFormatFlags(kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsPacked),
            mBytesPerPacket: UInt32(bytesPerPacket),
            mFramesPerPacket: UInt32(framesPerPacket),
            mBytesPerFrame: UInt32(bytesPerSample * channelsPerFrame),
            mChannelsPerFrame: UInt32(channelsPerFrame),
            mBitsPerChannel: UInt32(MemoryLayout<Int16>.size * 8),
            mReserved: 0
        )
        maxSampleCount = sampleRate * seconds
        //UnsafeMutablePointer使用の基本は
        //allocate -> initialize -> (使用) -> deinitialize -> deallocate のAIDDカルテット
        buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer.allocate(capacity: maxSampleCount)
        buffer.initialize(repeating: 0, count: maxSampleCount)
    }

    deinit {
        buffer.deinitialize(count: maxSampleCount)
        buffer.deallocate()
        if let audioQueueObject = audioQueueObject {
            AudioQueueStop(audioQueueObject, true)
            AudioQueueDispose(audioQueueObject, true)
            self.audioQueueObject = nil
        }
    }

    func startRecord() {
        print(#function)
        guard audioQueueObject == nil else  { return }
        data = nil
        prepareForRecord()
        let err: OSStatus = AudioQueueStart(audioQueueObject!, nil)
        print("err: \(err)")
    }

    func stopRecord() {
        print(#function, "usingSampleCount:", usingSampleCount)
        //領域が途中で途切れているかもしれないので、`bytesNoCopy`など連続した領域をあてにしたイニシャライザは使えない
        var data = Data(count: usingSampleCount * bytesPerSample)
        data.withUnsafeMutableBytes { (dataBytes: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int16>) in
            if startingSampleIndex + usingSampleCount <= maxSampleCount {
                dataBytes.assign(from: buffer.advanced(by: startingSampleIndex), count: usingSampleCount)
            } else {
                let firstReadCount = maxSampleCount - startingSampleIndex
                dataBytes.assign(from: buffer.advanced(by: startingSampleIndex), count: firstReadCount)
                dataBytes.advanced(by: firstReadCount).assign(from: buffer, count: usingSampleCount - firstReadCount)
            }
        }
        self.data = data
        guard let audioQueueObject = audioQueueObject else  { return }
        AudioQueueStop(audioQueueObject, true)
        AudioQueueDispose(audioQueueObject, true)
        self.audioQueueObject = nil
    }

    func play() {
        print(#function)
        guard audioQueueObject == nil else  { return }
        prepareForPlay()
        let err: OSStatus = AudioQueueStart(audioQueueObject!, nil)
        print("err: \(err)")
    }

    func stop() {
        print(#function)
        guard let audioQueueObject = audioQueueObject else  { return }
        AudioQueueStop(audioQueueObject, true)
        AudioQueueDispose(audioQueueObject, true)
        self.audioQueueObject = nil
    }

    func setData(_ data: Data) {
        self.data = data
        var writeLen = data.count/bytesPerSample
        if writeLen > maxSampleCount {writeLen = maxSampleCount}
        data.withUnsafeBytes{ (dataPtr: UnsafePointer<Int16>) in
            buffer.assign(from: dataPtr, count: writeLen)
        }
        startingSampleIndex = 0
        usingSampleCount = writeLen
    }

    private func prepareForRecord() {
        print(#function)
        var audioFormat = self.audioFormat

        startingSampleIndex = 0
        usingSampleCount = 0

        AudioQueueNewInput(&audioFormat,
                           myAudioQueueInputCallback,
                           Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque(),
                           CFRunLoopGetCurrent(),
                           CFRunLoopMode.commonModes.rawValue,
                           0,
                           &audioQueueObject)

        let bufferByteSize = numSamplesToWrite * bytesPerSample
        for _ in 0..<inBufferCount {
            var buffer: AudioQueueBufferRef? = nil
            AudioQueueAllocateBuffer(audioQueueObject!, UInt32(bufferByteSize), &buffer)
            AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(audioQueueObject!, buffer!, 0, nil)
        }
    }

    private func prepareForPlay() {
        print(#function)
        var audioFormat = self.audioFormat

        AudioQueueNewOutput(&audioFormat,
                            myAudioQueueOutputCallback,
                            Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque(),
                            CFRunLoopGetCurrent(),
                            CFRunLoopMode.commonModes.rawValue,
                            0,
                            &audioQueueObject)

        playingSampleIndex = startingSampleIndex
        playingSampleCount = usingSampleCount

        let bufferByteSize = numSamplesToWrite * bytesPerSample
        for _ in 0..<outBufferCount {
            var buffer: AudioQueueBufferRef? = nil
            AudioQueueAllocateBuffer(audioQueueObject!, UInt32(bufferByteSize), &buffer)
            myAudioQueueOutputCallback(inUserData: Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque(),
                                       inAQ: audioQueueObject!,
                                       inBuffer: buffer!)
        }
    }

    func readSamples(inBuffer: AudioQueueBufferRef) {
        print(#function)
        var numSamples = playingSampleCount
        if numSamples > numSamplesToRead {
            numSamples = numSamplesToRead
        }

        if numSamples > 0 {
            //outBuffer内のポインタをUnsafePointer<Int16>に変換
            let outSamples = inBuffer.pointee.mAudioData.assumingMemoryBound(to: Int16.self)
            if playingSampleIndex + numSamples <= maxSampleCount {
                //連続して読み出せる場合
                outSamples.assign(from: buffer.advanced(by: playingSampleIndex), count: numSamples)
            } else {
                let firstReadCount = maxSampleCount - playingSampleIndex
                outSamples.assign(from: buffer.advanced(by: playingSampleIndex), count: firstReadCount)
                outSamples.advanced(by: firstReadCount).assign(from: buffer, count: numSamples - firstReadCount)
            }
            inBuffer.pointee.mAudioDataByteSize = UInt32(bytesPerSample * numSamples)
            inBuffer.pointee.mPacketDescriptionCount = UInt32(numSamples)
            playingSampleIndex += numSamples
            playingSampleIndex %= maxSampleCount
            playingSampleCount -= numSamples
        } else {
            inBuffer.pointee.mAudioDataByteSize = 0
            inBuffer.pointee.mPacketDescriptionCount = 0
        }
    }

    func writeSamples(inBuffer: AudioQueueBufferRef) {
        print(#function)
        print("mAudioDataByteSize: \(inBuffer.pointee.mAudioDataByteSize), numPackets: \(inBuffer.pointee.mAudioDataByteSize / 2)")
        //inBuffer内のポインタをUnsafePointer<Int16>に変換
        var inSamples = inBuffer.pointee.mAudioData.assumingMemoryBound(to: Int16.self)
        //inBuffer内の標本数を求める
        var numSamples = Int(inBuffer.pointee.mAudioDataByteSize) / bytesPerSample
        //はみ出す場合に古いデータを消す処理
        if numSamples > maxSampleCount {
            //inBuffer内の標本数がバッファの最大を超える場合、inBufferの後ろのデータを入るだけ詰め込む
            inSamples = inSamples.advanced(by: numSamples - maxSampleCount)
            numSamples = maxSampleCount
            //バッファの中身は空にする
            startingSampleIndex = 0
            usingSampleCount = 0
        } else if numSamples > maxSampleCount - usingSampleCount {
            //inBuffer内の標本数がバッファの空き容量を超える場合
            //バッファ内の古い要素は捨てる
            startingSampleIndex += numSamples - (maxSampleCount - usingSampleCount)
            usingSampleCount -= numSamples - (maxSampleCount - usingSampleCount)
            //末尾を超えたら先頭に回す
            startingSampleIndex %= maxSampleCount
        }
        //次に書き込むべき位置を求める
        let writingSampleIndex = (startingSampleIndex + usingSampleCount) % maxSampleCount
        if writingSampleIndex + numSamples <= maxSampleCount {
            //全データ一気に書き込めるなら一回で終了
            buffer.advanced(by: writingSampleIndex).assign(from: inSamples, count: numSamples)
        } else {
            //バッファの末尾までの収まる標本数を求める
            let firstWriteCount = maxSampleCount - writingSampleIndex
            //上で求めた標本数分だけwritingSampleIndexから書き込み
            buffer.advanced(by: writingSampleIndex).assign(from: inSamples, count: firstWriteCount)
            //残りを先頭に書き込む
            buffer.assign(from: inSamples.advanced(by: firstWriteCount), count: numSamples - firstWriteCount)
        }
        usingSampleCount += numSamples
    }
}
```

関連して、元プロジェクトの他の場所でも幾らかの修正が必要になります。また[別質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/49411/13972)のコメントに書かれていたように`NSData`からの標本データの読み取りが間違っているようなので、そちらも修正した方がいいでしょう。もうご自分で修正された版を持っていると思いますが、私が書くならこんな感じということで。

```
import Cocoa

final class MyWaveView: NSView {
    //Swiftなんで、`NSData`は使用せずに`Data`を使用する
    var data: Data? {
        didSet {
            needsDisplay = true
        }
    }

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        NSColor.white.set()
        NSBezierPath(rect: bounds).fill()
        NSColor.darkGray.set()
        NSBezierPath(rect: bounds).stroke()

        guard let data = data else { return }

        let bezierPath = NSBezierPath()
        let length = data.count / MemoryLayout<Int16>.stride
        let unit = bounds.width / CGFloat(length)
        let mid = bounds.height / 2
        //`Data`内のデータへのポインタを`UnsafePointer<Int16>`型として取得する場合の書き方
        data.withUnsafeBytes { (samples: UnsafePointer<Int16>) in
            bezierPath.move(to: NSPoint(x: 0, y: mid))
            for index in 0 ..< length {
                let normalizedSample = CGFloat(samples[index]) / CGFloat(Int16.max)
                bezierPath.line(to: NSPoint(x: unit * CGFloat(index), y: normalizedSample * mid + mid))
            }
        }
        NSColor.black.set()
        bezierPath.lineWidth = 1
        bezierPath.stroke()
    }
}
```

書き換え部分がかなり大きくなったので、つまらないミスが入っているかもしれません。お気付きの点があればご質問ともどもお知らせください。

ちなみに解析処理はもう書かれているということですが、それとうまくつながるようになんてことは一切考えていません。ご自身のコードは今どのようなものになっているのでしょうか？参考サイトの元プロジェクトからは解析処理の追加などを含め、色々変更されているかと思います。ご質問を書かれるときに肝心なところはご質問そのものに含めていただいていると思いますが、思わぬ部分に影響が出ることもあります。出来ればご自身のリポジトリをGithub等に持たれて、ご質問本文には入れていないコードも見られるようにしてもらった方が良いかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。少し時間がかかってしまうと思いますが、じっくり読んで落とし込みたいと思います。いつもOOPerさんの回答は大変勉強になります。Githubについて確かに持っておいた方が良いと自分でも思いました。機会を見て持ちたいと思います。

Comment: Data型から値を取得しようとしたのですが、できませんでした。
let a = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Int16>.allocate(capacity: data.count/2)
data!.copyBytes(to: a, data!.indices[0] )このようにコピーできるかと試してみましたが、うまくいきませんでした。どのように取得すればよろしいでしょうか。

Comment: このように取得してみました。あっておりますでしょうか。最終的にarrが欲しい配列[Int16]の想定です。let b = data.withUnsafeMutableBytes{(pointer:UnsafeMutablePointer<Int16>) in
                    return pointer
                };  let arr = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Int16>(start: b, count: data.count/2);   _ = data.copyBytes(to: arr,from: data.startIndex..<data.endIndex)